# Protractor clicking through an array of elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I'm quite new to e2e testing and in using protractor / jasmine framework. I know how to get an array of elements and also how to click on an anchor. But how would / is it even possible to click through a list of anchors returned by a element selector / repeater?

I've been trying various ways, but as an example (latest one which hasn't been deleted lol) this is what I got:

```
element.all(by.repeater('link in links')).then(function(links) {
    links.forEach(function(link) {

        link.click().then(function() {
            console.log('callback for click ');

        });
    });
});
```

This appears to take the first element and click through, however come the next iteration it hangs (I can see why, but struggling to figure a way to resolve - is this some kind of promise & resolve factor i need to take into account?)

The error coming back is

> Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Any guidance / link to help would be appreciated - googling hasn't returned anything of note to me so far...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try the following : `element.all(by.repeater('link in links')).then(function(links){
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
            (function(test){
                links.get(i).click();
            })(links[i]);
        }
    });` Sorry for the bad markup but I didn't think it was worthy of being an answer since it's a guess at most.

Comment: Hey, no worries. I did try something similar. Unfortunately this returns an error saying the object has no method 'get' --> Failed: Object [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] has no method 'get'

Comment: I assume you've tried the same but instead of `links.get(i).click`, `links[i].click`?

Comment: @TomNijs I tried replacing `links.get(i).click();` with `test.click();` however this returns the same **stale element reference** error in original post :(

Comment: @TomNijs `links[i].click` returns same stale element issue

Comment: Could you include some relevant HTML code? I'm trying to reproduce this as accurately as possible. And what exactly do the links do? If they redirect the user, or change the DOM in any way this could indicate the `stale element reference` error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76081/discussion-between-tom-nijs-and-sukh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure a workaround, although this doesn't feel quite right. Anyway, if anyone has better suggestion feel free to post :)

```
element.all(by.repeater('link in links')).map(
    function(link, index) {
        return {
            index: index,
            href: link.getAttribute('href')
        };
    })
    .then(function(links) {
        for (var i = links.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        browser.get(links[i].href);
        // do some page specific stuff here.
    };
});
```

Comment: I have found an easier solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/42512582/3206885

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the "staleness" problem, you have to get an array of `href` resolved attribute values, which `map()`+`then()` can help you with (as you've already provided). You just don't need `index` and you can iterate over links starting from the first:

```
element.all(by.repeater('link in links')).map(function(link) {
    return link.getAttribute('href');
}).then(function(links) {
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        browser.get(links[i]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 01

```
public findSpecificElementAndClick(element: ElementArrayFinder,expected: number){
        let clickedIndex: number = -1;
        element.filter(function (elementItem, index) {
            clickedIndex++;
            if(index === (expected-1)){
                element.get(clickedIndex).click();
                return true;
            }
        }).then(function (bool) {

        }).catch(function (err) {
            throw new FrameworkException('Ooops ! Error... '+err.message);
        });
    }
```

Solution 02

```
public findTextAndClick(element: ElementArrayFinder,expected: string) {
        let clickedIndex: number = -1;
        let status :boolean = false;
        element.filter(function (elementItem, index) {
            return elementItem.getText().then(function (text) {
                if(text === expected) {
                    clickedIndex = index;
                    status = true;
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }).then(function (bool) {
            if(!status){
                throw new ApplicationException("Ooops ! Couldn't found "+expected+" Record ...");
            }else{
                element.get(clickedIndex).click();
            }
        }).catch(function (err) {
            throw new FrameworkException('Ooops ! Error... '+err.message);
        });
    }
```