# Protractor map function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Given an app with multiple widgets on it, each with their own title and whatnot, I would like to map each widget's elements, to make them easy to handle in tests.

For example, a page:

```
this.widgets = element.all(by.css('ul.widget-grid')).map(function(widget, index) {
    return {
        index: index,
        title: widget.element(by.css('div.title')).getText()
    };
});
```

And then in my spec:

```
expect(page.widgets[0].index).toBe(0);
expect(page.widgets[0].title).toBe('The Title');
```

Unfortunately, my expects are returning `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Protractor 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This confused me so I thought I'd add an answer to help others...

While I understood that `map()` returns a promise, because I was using it in an `expect`, I thought it would be resolved, and then should act like an array. Nope. It returns an object, that looks like an array, but is *not* an array.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem, and none of these solved this for me. For anyone googling like I was here is the real answer:

```
element.all(by.css('ul.widget-grid')).map(function(widget, index) {
    return {
        index: index,
        title: widget.element(by.css('div.title')).getText()
    }
}).then(function(map){
      this.widgets = map;
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

[`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) returns a promise that would resolve into an **array** of objects.

I think you meant to check the first widget's index and title:

```
var widget = page.widgets[0];

expect(widget.index).toBe(0);
expect(widget.title).toBe('The Title');
```

Comment: Sorry, alecxe, that was a typo on my part. I'm using indexes. I updated my question. It's still always returning undefined no matter what I try.

Comment: @Brine alright, can you post the exact error text? Thanks.

Comment: Using your example alecxe, I'm getting: `Failed: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined`

Comment: @Brine let's debug it a little bit. What would be printed if you add this: `this.widgets.then(function (widgets) { console.log(widgets); });`?

Comment: @Brine if it's gonna be `[]` - you have no elements matching `ul.widget-grid` CSS selector.

Comment: I'm with you @alecxe. That's why I'm wondering if `map` is busted in 2.0. 'Cause when I ran `this.widgets.then(function (widgets) { console.log(widgets); });` I get `[ ]`; but when I run `console.log(element.all(by.css('ul.widget-grid')));`, I get `[object Object]`... as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Protractor's [ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) gave me some hard time.
The solution that worked for me was a good old `for` loop:

```
 var myElements = element.all(by.css('ul li')) - 1;
 var n = myElements.length - 1;

 for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     var elem = myElements.get(i);
     var open = elem.element(by.css('.some-class'));
     open.click();
     var childElem = filter.element(by.css('[some-attribute]'));
     expect(childElem.isPresent()).toBe(true);
 }
```

Comment: what does the -1 at the end of: `var myElements = element.all(by.css('ul li')) - 1;`

do ?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've worked on that. I think it's something to do with array indexing. Check the docs https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder for details. You can also do a quick test to see what it actually does.